# rotating the hand with its bones to another position makes it distorted

Tags: armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

I have connected the hand with the bones as shown but now I need to move the complete model to another location before I articulate the bones into a final position. However, the hand becomes distorted. Is there a setting I have missed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are scaling the model. If you do that or any translation on the mesh alone with an unaffected armature connected, you’re going to have problems. Besides, the mesh is patented to the armature, so you should move the armature.

Comment: @TheLabCat: Thanks. I had the armature hidden. Didnt realise all connected entities needed to be shown prior to rotation